# Process 9-Patch Image with ImageMagick

Tags: android, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

How do I do something with a 9-Patch image with ImageMagick?

To simplify, I need to apply any ImageMagick operation on a rectangle that starts at upper-left at `(1, 1)` and ends at lower-right at `(width - 2, height - 2)`. The operation must not touch the 1 pixel border of the image.

For example, I want to replace the colors in the rectangle described above. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe something like `-region +1+1 -gravity SouthEast -region -1-1 ...` ?

Comment: -region should work but like -crop you need a size and offset so it would be something like -region 100x200+1+1 -colorspace gray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this. It kind of depends what you want to do in the middle bit :-)

One way, is to clone the image, and shave off a 1 pixel border all the way round, do your operations on the *"slightly smaller"* image and then composite the result back into the original.

```
convert -gravity center image.png                   \
  \( +clone -shave 1x1 -fill blue -colorize 100% \) \
  -composite result.png
```

So, I start with a red rectangle, copy and shave, fill with blue and then paste.

[image]

Comment: This works. Thank you! (It is slightly slow though.)